# Start up a express server on browser in an Angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I know it's kind of awkward question, but is it possible to start up an express server on the browser (basically run an express server on client's side i.e. when user clicks on a button) of an Angular app?

The server on client's side would be very simple, basically define a route that would be later used by the app. (like a local call - 127.0.0.1/myRoute)

Has anyone ever seen anything like that?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not possible, because it is not the web browser role. Why do you need this?

Comment: Certainly. What happens is that the client wants us to use a library (npm package) that runs on node side only. There is no other package available for angular project, as there are some limitations involved. So if it is possible to start a simple server on client's side would be good. I agree it's a tricky idea, but who knows. I have seen something like Browserify (http://browserify.org) that bundles required node modules for running in a browser, but even so I am not quite sure it's work out.